# How do you get the secret achievements?

Tags: dungeon-warfare

This game currently has [5 secret achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/355980/achievements):

- They are just for decoration
- Grand Grandmaster
- All your base are belong to us
- No knocks allowed
- The box without a box

How do you unlock them?

Comment: sorry it's a secret, I can't tell you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer [from the developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/355980/discussions/0/496880503064194458/?tscn=1446767627#c496880503064245460):

> They are hidden because they are in development yet. We'll unveil them soon.